# Ecobee installation with a air circulation unit?

Tags: hvac

I recently had a technician install a new ecobee thermostat, but he disconnected the control board from on top of the furnace.  he bypassed the board to install the thermostat.  Is there a way to manually wire the aprilaire fresh air circulation into the thermostat, or is it better just to remove that from the system?  I have another thermostat I am looking to replace which will be in the same situation.  There are only 3 wires to the builder installed thermostat (red, white, and blue) labeled 1,2, and 3 respectively.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. It's hard to know what you're talking about; would you add information (e.g. make/model of the furnace) and perhaps a picture or two? And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: Can you post make/model information for all equipment involved, as well as wiring diagrams and photos of the control wiring?